# How to unwrap Optional<Optional<T>> in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift

Let's say we have `String??` value. `Optional` of `Optional` may have 3 states:

```
let strOptOpt1: String?? = .Some(.Some("actual value"))
let strOptOpt2: String?? = .Some(.None)
let strOptOpt3: String?? = .None
```

To safely unwrap them to `String`, in Swift 1.1 we could:

```
if let str:String = strOptOpt? {
    println(str)
}
else {
    println("was nil") // `.Some(.None)` or `.None`
}
```

But it does not work anymore in Swift 1.2:

```
if let str:String = strOptOpt? {
//                           ^ [!] error: '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript
```

At the moment, I think, I have to do like this:

```
if let strOpt = strOptOpt, str = strOpt {
    println(str)
}
```

OR using `switch`:

```
switch strOptOpt {
case let .Some(.Some(str)):
    println(str)
default:
    println("was nil")
}
```

But, there must be simpler way to do this, I think. Anyone know that?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: I've posted a query for you on devforums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1107132#1107132

Comment: I hoped that you would :)

Comment: So my example is not an example of the problem you're talking about? - I keep tripping over this new extra `@objc` attribute that we need. The compiler should at least warn me: "Okay, but this isn't going to work because your optional member isn't visible to Objective-C".

Comment: I think so. I want to unwrap `String??` directly to `String`. Swift 1.1 have the way, but not in 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

As of Swift 2, you can use `if/case` with a pattern, and `x?` as
a synonym for `.Some(x)`:

```
if case let str?? = strOptOpt1 {
    print(str)
} else {
    print("was nil") // `.Some(.None)` or `.None`
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know we can use `x?` as a synonym for `.Some(x)`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best solution I found is using `??` operator in optional binding.

```
let strOptOpt: String?? = ...

if let str = strOptOpt ?? nil {
    println(str) // "actual value"
}
```

Works for all these cases:

- `.Some(.Some("actual value"))`
- `.Some(.None)`
- `.None`

But, if `strOptOpt` is `String???`, you should do:

```
let strOptOpt: String??? = ...

if let str = (strOptOpt ?? nil) ?? nil {
    println(str)
}
```

Comment: Nice! See also "Nil Coalescing Operator"  (which is the ?? operator) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks for the answer and it works. The only downside of this method is:  even for `str: String??`, `if let str = (((str ?? nil) ?? nil) ?? nil) ?? nil { ... }` is valid. In Swift 1.1, the compiler successfully warns us if we type extra `?` like `if let str = str??? { }`.

Answer (score 0):

I always get double optional in this situation

```
let field: ChangeField?? = json["field_id"].int.map{ ChangeField(rawValue: $0) }
```

Instead of `map` you can use `flatMap`

```
let field: ChangeField? = json["field_id"].int.flatMap{ ChangeField(rawValue: $0) }
```