# How do you perform optional binding on an optional of optional?

Tags: swift, option-type, optional-binding

How do you do optional binding on an optional of optional?

For example, assume UIViewController's navigationController property is an optional of optional.  Should I use method #1 or method #2, or is there a third way?

Method #1

```
if let navigationController = viewController.navigationController! {

}
```

or

Method #2

```
if let optionalNavigationController = viewController.navigationController {
   let navigationController = optionalNavigationController {

    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to unwrap Optional<Optional<T>> in Swift 1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724946/how-to-unwrap-optionaloptionalt-in-swift-1-2).

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution:

```
if let stillOptional = viewController.navigationController, let notOptional = stillOptional {
    //use notOptional here
}
```

Comment: Method #1 I listed seems cleaner since it's only one level?

Comment: @Boon it is cleaner, but if `navigationController` is `nil`, it will crash because of the forced unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let navigationController = viewController?.navigationController
```

Comment: Why optional on viewController?

Comment: [Optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Comment: ViewController is not an optional in this case, why chain it?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was confused.

Answer (score 0):

Much more functional-programming solution:

```
if let a = optionalOfOptional?.map({$0}) {
    println(a)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **know** that the view controller has a navigation controller, because you designed it in Interface Builder or created it programmatically, declare a variable

```
var navigationController : UINavigationController!
```

and assign the navigation controller in `viewDidLoad()` as implicit unwrapped optional

```
navigationController = viewController!.navigationController!
```

If you don't know, use a normal optional binding as described in the other answers